# Does tc guarantee network bandwidth for a process or run as best effort?

Tags: bandwidth, tc, traffic-shaping, bandwidth-control

I have a tc rule as follows:

```
qdisc tbf 1: dev bwp93ce2ea9d929 root refcnt 2 rate 100Mbit burst 100Kb lat 25.0ms
```

Is this rule guarantee network bandwidth to be 100Mbps or it'll throttle if not enough network bandwidth is available at the moment?

If tc is not providing a guaranteed slice of bandwidth, then what's the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not guaranteed. It only limits the bandwidth of that process to a certain rate without guarantying any bandwidth.